# git - where I should put the .git folder?

Tags: git, github, repository

I'm developing a website and I wonder where I should put the .git folder ? in the same dir of the /var/www/html/mysite?

I got GitHub account btw, what do you think its good or there is better providers?

Comment: You create a repository ("put the .git folder", `git init`) in the directory containing everything you want to track, but no more.

Comment: If `/var/www/html/mysite` is the folder which has the contents you want to track and manage using git, then executing `git init` in that folder will create the `.git` folder for you. You dont have to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new repository outside the DocumentRoot of your webserver. Copy your website into this new repo and run

```
git init
```

This might be inefficient when you make changes to your website, but I wouldn't want visitors viewing the contents of my .git folder...

Comment: There are other ways to prevent someone from viewing a given directory through your web server...

Answer (score 2):

http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto is a great guide on this common task.

The basics are that you want to create a **bare** repo (with `git init --bare`) outside of your webservers DocumentRoot and add a post-receive hook to the repo that updates the website contents inside the DocumentRoot when you push to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can also look into [code.google.com](http://code.google.com) and use [subversion](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ) - they allow you to host your code for up to 2GB. Others include SourceForge, BitBucket, etc.

Since you're using Apache, you don't necessarily need to put your git folder in your /var/www/* because you can modify the apachet directives to point wherever you feel more confortable on the system. find the instructions on how to do this [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=243804)

If choosing to set your Apache folder elsewhere on the system beware of setting the folder permissions so that they can be published on the web using chmod 711 folder/